# What decides which python class' main() is run

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a tool that displays parameterized data on a dedicated monitor.

Following what I've learned in java, I name the method containing the "calling" code `main()`.  I then call this `main()` at the end of the file.  The problem is, for some reason when I run `python file1` in the command prompt, it runs the main from file2.  File1 imports file 2, but since avoided the namespace collision over `main()` by not writing `from file2 import*`, I'm not sure it's running the other file's `main()`.

I'm running windows 7 Ultimate, python 3.4

Comment: How are you calling `main` in file1?

Comment: @Engineero just the statement main() at the last line, without a class specifier, I assume that would default to the local class in file 1

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does \`if \_\_name\_\_ == "\_\_main\_\_":\` do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: @joshsvoss, are you also calling main in file 2? In that case the above link will help you.

Comment: Everything written in the global scope of the module is executed when the code is loaded. In your case, when you import file2, the function is called. Do not call anything directly in the module scope unless you know what you're doing; for executing a main function you can check the special variable `__name__` which is set to `"__main__"` if the module is the main module, and the module's name otherwise. See the question linked by otus for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` is just a Python variable that points to the function object. If you assign the `main` a different value, you loose the reference to the original function. If you define the `main` after the import, then your own `main` will be used.

**Update:** If both `file1.py` and `file2.py` contain the definition of the `main()` function and if both call it in the file -- say as the last line in its own file, and if the `file1.py` does `import file2`--but does not `from file2 import *` after the `main()` definition in the `file1.py`--then both `main()` functions will be called. The `file2.main()` is called during the `import file2` (the first import in the application only), and the `file1.main()` is going to be called when the `main()` call in `file1.py` is found.

Whenever `xxx.py` is launched as a script, it is processed in the order of the source text. Processing of a definition means compilation of the definition, when a command is found during the first read, it is executed (actually after compilation to `xxx.pyc` first).

The only way to avoid execution of a code in your file is to jump over the code fragment using `if` with suitable condition. This is why the pattern

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

is used in the sources. (Which actually is the execution of the code -- only the branch of the `if` is skipped.) Read it... If the file is launched as a script, then the `__name__` variable takes the string value `'__main__'`, the condition holds and the `main()` from this file is called.

If the same pattern is used in the `file2.py`, and the file is used as a module (that is `import file2`), then the `__name__` variable contains the name of the imported module (here `file2`), and the condition does not hold. Because of that, the `main()` from inside `file2.py` is not called.

The pattern is often used even in the files that are expected to be used as modules only. The code is usually used for testing the basic functionality of the module. Think about the situation when the author of the module makes some changes. Then he/she launches it as a script (which is not usually doney), and the body starts testing of the module and reports the result -- say using `unittest` module or whatever kind of testing. So, the `file2.main()` would be a good place to activate unit testing, for example.

Try to add the following to the end of your `file1.py`:

```
print(__name__)
print(file2.__name__)
```

Answer (score 2):

Look into using the `__name__` variable to specify which `main()` you want to run.

For an example, check out: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)